# Magento 2 slider extension

Tags: magento2

I have downloaded free image `slider(MagebannerSlider)`. I want to use it but without upgrading the setup. When I run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

it appears in the Content section of backend, if I just put the `bannerSlider` in the `app->code->bannerSlider` it is not working.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

type commands:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magestore_Bannerslider

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

First is to enable the module/plugin.
Second to upgrade setup. (db)
Last to get static files deployed.

Maybe clear cache too.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```